# How to evaluate the Lebesgue integral of the Heaviside function?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have to evaluate the Lebesgue integral

$$
I = \int\limits_{[-1, 1]} \chi(x) \chi(x - \frac{1}{2})     d\left(\chi(x)\chi(x + \frac{1}{2})\right)
$$

where $ \chi $ is the [Heaviside function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function):
$$
\chi(x) = \begin{cases}0, & x < 0 \\ 1, & x \geq 0 \end{cases}
$$

The solution given is $$
I = \int\limits_{[-1, 1]} \chi(x) \chi(x - \frac{1}{2})d\left(\chi(x)\right) = \chi(0)\chi(-\frac{1}{2}) = 0 $$

but I'm unable to grasp it. Specifically, I don't understand what happened to $d\left(\chi(x)\chi(x + \frac{1}{2})\right)$.

Can you help me understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working in $[-1,1]$, we have $\chi(x) \chi(x - \frac{1}{2}) =\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}(x)$ and $\chi(x)\chi(x + \frac{1}{2})=\chi_{[-1,-\frac{1}{2}]}(x),\ $so upon using the definition of the integral, we get

$\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}(-1/2)-\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}(-1)=0-0$

More specifically, observe that $d\left(\chi(x)\chi(x + \frac{1}{2})\right)$ refers the measure $\mu$, defined by $\mu ([-1,x))=\chi(x)\chi(x + \frac{1}{2})$, which as we just saw, is equal to $\chi_{[-1,-\frac{1}{2}]}(x)$

Now, $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}$ is a simple function, so by definition of the Lebesgue-Stieljes integral,

$\int _{[-1,1]}\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}d\mu=1\cdot\mu([\frac{1}{2},1])=1\cdot \mu ([-1,1])-\mu ([-1,\frac{1}{2}])=\chi_{[-1,-\frac{1}{2}]}(1)-\chi_{[-1,-\frac{1}{2}]}(\frac{1}{2})=0-0=0.$

Remark: this all makes intuitive sense since $\mu$ is concentration in the zero set of $\chi_{[\frac{1}{2},1]}(x)$

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!